# Extracting Text Between two Characters in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office

I have an xls collumn with the following template:

```
Model : QE85Q80T,Diagonala cm / inch : 216 cm / 85 inch,Smart TV : Da,Format : Ultra HD 4K,Tip ecran : QLED,Rezolutie (pixeli) : 3840 x 2160,Tuner Digital : Da (DVB-T2 / C / S2) x 2,Difuzor integrat : 60 W,Wireless : Da,Ethernet : Da,Iesire audio digitala (optica) : x 1,CI (Slot) : PLUS,USB 2.0 : x 2,HDMI : x 4,Culoare : Negru,Putere consumata (W) : 257,Dimensiuni cu stand (mm) : 1892.8 x 1163.1 x 338.8,Greutate (Kg) : 50.1
```

Please note the variables: "Diagonala cm / inch"; "Smart TV"; "Format" and so on...

All of them can have different values.

What i try to acomplish is to extract in a different cell the value between "**Diagonala cm / inch :** " and first "**,**" - in this case the value would be "**216 cm / 85 inch**".

Same thing in another cell with the value between "**Smart TV :** " and first "**,**" - the value would been "**Da**" and so on for the rest...

After multiple searches on google i've come up with the formula:

> =MID(F2,SEARCH("**Diagonala cm / inch :** ",F2)+3,SEARCH("**,**",F2)-SEARCH("**Diagonala cm / inch :** ",F2)-4)

The issue is it doesn't give me back anything.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: @Isolated hi there! how to do that?

Comment: I deleted my comment because I'm not sure if that's the correct way to think about it. I'm thinking about this a bit, and will provide something if I figure it out.

Comment: As you need multiple results I think [text to columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7) is a better option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("Diagonala cm / inch : ",A1)+LEN("Diagonala cm / inch : "),999),-1+FIND(",",MID(A1,FIND("Diagonala cm / inch : ",A1)+LEN("Diagonala cm / inch : "),999)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it seems this is what i needed

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is ugly and works, but not sure how this will adapt to your needs. I think it will if you have references. At any rate, here is the formula:

```
    =MID(B2,(SEARCH("Diagonala cm / inch :",B2)+LEN("Diagonala cm / inch :")),(SEARCH(",",B2,SEARCH("Diagonala cm / inch :",B2))-(SEARCH("Diagonala cm / inch :",B2)+LEN("Diagonala cm / inch :"))))
```

And here's how I came up with it:

[image]

Basically, the formula returns the same results as

```
    =mid(b2,39,17)
```

Answer (score 0):

For what to use, perhaps one would like the following approach:

```
=LET(SearchCell,A1,  StartingString,"Diagonala cm / inch : ",  EndingString,",",    MID(SearchCell,  FIND(StartingString,SearchCell)  +  LEN(StartingString),  FIND(EndingString,SearchCell,1+FIND(StartingString,SearchCell))  -  (FIND(StartingString,SearchCell)+LEN(StartingString))  )  )
```

(I like `Isolated`'s use of `LEN()` to avoid hardcoding the string's length. One would know it, of course, so it wouldn't be an issue, but it stops there, so to speak, and is not easily extensible to a more general solution that one might want to achieve after writing the basic formula and using it for a while. Upgrading should be helped when possible!)

The approach is to find the starting point of the desired result, then the ending point and so the number of characters required from the input string. Hence `FIND()` and the addition of the locating string's length. And also the `FIND()` to locate the "," after that point which needs the starting point with 1 added to it for `FIND()` to begin there and not be confused by earlier commas.

That's straightforward and what they call "ugly"... oh well... For the upgrade, use the `LET()` function. One could get pretty carried away with that, but I suggest only using it for the changing inputs to the formula:  the cell to look in, the starting string, and the ending string. That way, changing the cell looked in is easy as it occurs in only one place, not the six or so the formula uses it in. Also should speed it up since that's one calc, not six. The two boundary strings are also easy to edit as they are right there at the beginning too, so the formula can be easily adapted to take the second search asked for, and others. It also becomes pretty easy to use input cells to contain strings for the boundaries.

I think more use of `LET()` here would detract from understanding the work of the formula, though other brains work differently and might like to put its components into the `Let()` form of cell-scope named ranges (Excel reference there, programmers would call them variables) and then the working formula would be a minimal thing. If that would reduce the OVERALL size of the formula, I'd probably suggest doing that, but it wouldn't in this case, so... But truly, it would make the opposite sense to someone else, so for them, why not?

I assume anyone reading the problem would actually want the above, a way to accomplish what is discussed. But what is actually really asked is why did the given formula found via Google fail?

Basically, because it doesn't look for the right start, or calculate the right length of string to take. The first `SEEARCH()` for example:  it finds the boundary string's start and adds... 3... to it. For no good reason considering the logic of the formula is essentially the same used by these answers. One needs to begin the string being built by `MID()` AFTER the full boundary string. That string is 22 characters long, not 3, so... Then, the third parameter for `MID()`, the length of string to return, comes out wrong. It finds the comma preceding the boundary string and works from there to actually give a negative length and so an error. Other input data might give it an actual return but it really wouldn't ever give a correct return since it is using utterly wrong input choices. So correct those issues and you should have a working formula. Nice approach, not so nice implementation. But finding a good approach is almost always the harder thing! Just need to reconsider how you chosoe the details leading to the numbers generated as parameters for that poor `MID()` function.